# Is it acceptable to provide poor answers to your own Story-ID question?

Tags: discussion, story-identification, answer-quality

Typically, when there's a story-identification question that lists several points; and that question has a bad answer (e.g. an answer only stating the name of the work with ZERO information on how that work matches the points raised in the question); I downvote/flag/delete such an answer.

Why? Because there's no way for the reader to judge how correct the answer is, so it should be judged as "incorrect".

Should the same be applied when such a bad answer is provided by Original Poster of the question themselves?

On one hand, they KNOW for sure this is the correct answer. We don't have the same reason to downvote as the "why" above.

On the other hand, it wouldn't be fair to judge what would otherwise be a poor answer as "OK" merely on account of who posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's *not* acceptable. While I'm glad for the OP that *they* found their book, it doesn't help other users. Someone who thinks they're looking for the same book, doesn't know which details were correct and which weren't, and doesn't know any details that allows them to judge whether it really is the same book they're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

I feel it's acceptable (as in that it should be allowed), but should be *highly* discouraged, possibly even downvoted for not being particularly useful. These answers point *towards* the "correct" answer, even if it does not provide all the details a good answer might.

When "low-quality" answers pop up in the review queue, I only flag/vote to delete if the question is not addressed. If it at least *attempts* to answer the question, I vote to let it live and try to encourage the user to add more details. (Yes, I know that this is often an exercise in futility - especially with hit-and-run users.)

Answer (score 4):

I will say, for myself, that I always try to write self-answers to the same level, if not higher, as my other `story-identification` answers. I provide evidence, quotes, and if possible, how I found the work (although, often, this is a less-satisfying explanation of "Oh, yeah, I remembered this word I didn't mention in the question, and it took me right there because that's the title").